# Reading response from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, get, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am trying to call Javascript from Visualforce page. Below is the sample code of visualforce page. Here I am trying to call get method. I want to see response. Where it will saved? After clicking on preview in developer console JS will be executed. Where to see the response?

```
<apex:page controller="calljavascript_cls" >

<script>

function func()

{

 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var org_id = '***';
 var user_api_key = '******';

 request.open('GET', 'https://copado.herokuapp.com/json/v1/webhook/metadata/'+org_id+'?api_key='+user_api_key);

 request.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (this.readyState === 4) {
 console.log('Status:', this.status);
 console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
 console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
 }
 };

 request.send();
 }

  </script>

   <apex:outputText value="{!callfunc}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>

  </apex:page>
```

Below code is the JavaScript.

```
public class calljavascript_cls

{

public string callfunc{get;set;}
public calljavascript_cls()

{

 callfunc='<script> func(); </script>';

 }

 }
```

Comment: You can see response in the network tab in your browser. click the request then click response

Comment: Please let me know where exactly?

Comment: https://prod-cdn.sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/images/2017-01-20-14-18-28-6cacb9.png then click on response

Comment: But here I am trying in salesforce developer console. How to get the response?

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (request.readyState === 4) {
           if (request.status == 200) {
               console.log('Status:', request.status);
               console.log('Headers:', request.getAllResponseHeaders());
               console.log('Body:', request.responseText);
           }
           else if (request.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Getting the below error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://copado.herokuapp.com/json/v1/webhook/metadata/''?api_key=''' from origin 'https://diwakarg123-dev-ed--c.ap5.visual.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: You need header allow cross origin in your api script.

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`

Comment: Where and what exactly I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the response in

```
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       /* Returns a DOMString that contains the response to the request as text, 
        or null if the request was unsuccessful or has not yet been sent.
       */
       console.log(this.responseText);

       /*
         Returns an ArrayBuffer, Blob, Document, JavaScript object, or a DOMString, 
         depending on the value of XMLHttpRequest.responseType. that contains the 
         response entity body.
       */
       console.log(this.response);
    }
    else
    {
       console.log(this.status); 
    };
```

For more info, you can have a look on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest